# Mongoose: How can I findOneAndUpdate on an array property and push into that found array property?

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Given the following document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("588d121dc23324935a061108"),
    "game" : "/donut_fun",
    "__v" : 0,
    "rooms" : [
        {
            "members" : [ ],
            "timestamp" : 1485640221059,
            "roomname" : "fun times"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I query by the `game` and `roomname` properties with `findOneAndUpdate()` and push an object into the `members` array.

I was trying (with no success):

```
var player = {pid: 1234, pname: 'Fred'};
var query = {game: '/donut_fun', roomname: 'fun times'};
var update = {$push: {'rooms.$.members':player }};
GamesModel.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, {new: true, upsert:true}, function(err, doc){
  console.log(doc);  
});
```

Comment: You are missing the `rooms` array reference. Try `var query = {game: '/donut_fun', "rooms.roomname": 'fun times'};`

Comment: @Veeram thanks, that was it, not sure how I forgot that. Feel free to post as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: What does the $ bettwen rooms and members do ?

Comment: @1020rpz It's the positional operator, here are the docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#update-documents-in-an-array